# What difference does it add when you write それで or これで instead of それは/それが and これが/これは?

Tags: grammar, particles

What difference does it add when you write the で particle after words like それ and これ?

Comment: Please look up particle で in dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

これで can generally be translated as "with this". It's used to indicate the result or conclusion following some action or happening. For example:

> [今日]{きょう}の[活動]{かつどう}は、**これで**お[開]{ひら}き。
>
> **With this**, today's activities come to a close.

You can find more of these examples on [Jisho's sentence search](http://jisho.org/search/%22%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A7%22%20%23sentences).

For これは and これが, you need to look up the differences between は and が, which is a complex topic (but it's been answered many times before). Generally, they mean "this is".