# それで vs そうして in そうしてなおすんですか/それで勉強しているつもりですか

Tags: word-choice

Here are two sentences from "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar":

> それで勉強しているつもりですか。
> Are you sure you can study like that?

> そうしてなおすんですか。
> Oh, that's how you fix it?

It seems to me that in both of these sentences, それで and そうして are being used to mean "like that". Are they interchangeable in this context? Or is there some subtlety I'm missing?

Comment: The translation of the first sentence doesn’t seem correct. それで is not modifying 勉強する.

Comment: Related: [What difference does it add when you write それで or これで instead of それは/それが and これが/これは?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33592/43676)

Comment: I double checked, and those are how the sentences are written in dojg. There might be an error, but my Japanese isn't good enough to tell. Thanks for your helpful answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not interchangeable.

それで is それ marked with the particle で. In your example, it refers to the general situation in which the speaker sees the listener to be, or the manner in which the latter is doing something at the time. The sentence implies the listener is being idle or not studying hard enough by the speaker’s standards.

> それで勉強しているつもりですか。
> (lit.) Do you think you are studying with (the situation being) that?

そうして is そう followed by the て-form of the verb する. It is interchangeable with そのようにして or そうやって, although the first alternative sounds much more formal and the second a little more colloquial than そうして.

> そうして直すんですか。
> (lit.) Do you fix it by doing so?

If そうして is replaced with それで, the sentence would be understood as referring to some concrete tool or means.

> それで直すんですか。
> (lit.) Do you fix it with that (thing)?